# Simple Python TCP Server Not Sending the Entire Web Page

Tags: python, html, tcp

I'm a beginner compsci student and I'm trying to code a simple server in python that takes a .HTML page stored in the same directory and sends it to a client on the same network using a TCP connection.

This is my code:

```
from socket import *

serverPort = 8000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
# Prepare a sever socket
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))  # binds socket to port 8000
serverSocket.listen(1)  # waiting for client to initiate connection

while True:
    # Establish the connection
    print('Ready to serve...')
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    try:

        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        filename = message.split()[1]

        f = open(filename[1:].decode())
        outputdata = f.read()

        # Send one HTTP header line into socket
        http_response = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n'

        connectionSocket.send(http_response.encode())

        # Send the content of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())

        connectionSocket.send("\r\n".encode())
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        connectionSocket.send("\r\n".encode())
        # DO LATER
serverSocket.close()
sys.exit()
```

And this is my simple html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>My First Web Page</h1>

    <p>You have successfully accessed the Web Server</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

So far whenever I run my server and direct my browser to it, I only get the following served to me:

```
<p>You have successfully accessed the Web Server</p>
```

Along with the body and html tags after this. Checking the page source there's no header.

I ran Wireshark while trying to access my server and indeed it seems like I'm only sending through "You have successfully accessed the Web server" and onwards. This is despite the fact a print function shows I am definitely sending all the data in the file through the TCP connection.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Are you only allowed to use the socket library? Otherwise you could use libraries like http.server

Comment: @tschomacker i think we can import others but I feel like they wouldn't expect us to do something we haven't been introduced to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sending the protocol answer and headers, the actual response comes after two `\r\n` sequences.

Use this fixed code:

```
from socket import *

serverPort = 8000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
# Prepare a sever socket
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))  # binds socket to port 8000
serverSocket.listen(1)  # waiting for client to initiate connection

while True:
    # Establish the connection
    print('Ready to serve...')
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    try:

        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        filename = message.split()[1]

        f = open(filename[1:].decode())
        outputdata = f.read()

        # Send one HTTP header line into socket
        http_response = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n'

        connectionSocket.send(http_response.encode())
        connectionSocket.send("\r\n".encode())
        connectionSocket.send("\r\n".encode())

        # Send the content of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())

        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        # DO LATER
serverSocket.close()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! That did it. Can I ask why you had to remove the \r\n after the data was sent too?

Comment: @reetyn As far as I know there is no delimiter for the end of the response. You could leave it, but it will be part of the website html.

Comment: @reetyn If this answer helped you you may consider accepting the answer so that it helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `http.server` library

```py
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8080
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

source: https://www.afternerd.com/blog/python-http-server/

Comment: I don't know if I can because they definitely want us to use this line of code:  "for i in range(0, len(outputdata)): / connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())"